# How to start emulator on remote machine by using command line

Tags: jenkins, command-line, android-emulator

I have created emulator on remote machine (IP: `192.168.X.X`) and that is working fine. After that I created Jenkins Job to execute Appium Test. I need to launch Emulator on remote machine (IP: `192.168.X.X`) through Jenkins window batch commend.

Answer (score 0):

See Windows Sysinternals' [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx):

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems, ...
>
> Usage: `psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]`

Answer (score 0):

I created a batch file that contain cmd command to execute Emulator and execute that batch file.

CMD command to invoke emulator

emulator -avd 'Emulator Name' 
Emulator name you can get from command -> adb devices